# Command line utility displaying support information for packages and release?

Tags: command-line, package-management, release-management, support

Ubuntu has a command line utility that displays support date stats for a given installation, with at least summary information on packages that are or are not supported and the dates concerned.  It is mentioned in a comment for an answer for at least one question on askubuntu but I cannot remember the command ?

Comment: what kind of support information?

Answer (score 1):

```
ubuntu-support-status --show-all
```

I thought I might get a fast answer from someone, but I managed to revisit the machine I used it on and got it from bash history.